# Update MySql data row by clicking on dropdown selection with no submit

Tags: php, html

Am having hard time trying to setup this. I would like to update the query "Approval" for the row that has the same "Id", by simply clicking on one of the dropdown selections.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <input type="hidden" name="sickId" value="<?php echo clean($rows['sickId']); ?>" />
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
             <?php echo clean($rows['sickApproval']); ?>
             <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" name="approveChange">
            <li><a href="#" value="Pending">Pending</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" value="Approved">Approved</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" value="Not Approved">Not Approved</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

**This is my PHP:**

```
//Update Approval status


if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] == 'update') {

        $sickApprovalchange = htmlspecialchars($_POST['approveChange']);
        $sickId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['sickId']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE
                                    sickleave
                                SET
                                    sickApproval = ?
                                WHERE
                                    sickId = ?"
        );
        $stmt->bind_param('ss',
                                $sickApprovalchange,
                                $sickId
        );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

}

Am quite beginner in coding and am having hard time figuring out the right solution. Here is the scenario:

Once clicked on the drop down, there are 3 options : pending, approved, not approved.

If I click on one of these options, the data query will automatically update accordingly.

One rule, the data query to be updated needs to be the same row where sickId is matched in the beginning of the HTML.

Will Really appreciate a coder or programmer help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for this. Make javascript function which will fire when href is click get the value from this and send to your php script using ajax and get the data back from that script.